# Python Pydot How to Rotate Edge Label

Tags: python, decision-tree, pydot

I have a question about pydot. I created some nodes and connected them to other nodes. While making connections, I gave a label to the edges. How can we change the direction of these labels ?(eg parallel to the line).My code;

```
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('TOP', label='Weather'))
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('M1', label='t-shirt'))
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('M2', label='jacket'))
graph.add_node(pydot.Node('M3', label='umbrella'))
edge = pydot.Edge('TOP', 'M1', label = 'sunny')
graph.add_edge(edge)
edge = pydot.Edge('TOP', 'M2', label = 'windy')
graph.add_edge(edge)
edge = pydot.Edge('TOP', 'M3', label = 'rainy')
graph.add_edge(edge)
graph.write_png('output.png')
```

[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99eFL.png)

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to change the layout with the [rankdir](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir) attribute.

```
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph',rankdir="LR")
```

which results in

[image]